# Optimized way of multiple columns computation in Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

What is the optimized or best performing approach to solve below use case

Consider a data frame of 1 million rows and 100 columns of which our interest is on 1 column - message. I need to construct 3 new columns based on conditions of matching keywords presence in the message.

- Message : Stack overflow contribution towards code development is
  increasing day by day
- flag1 Keywords : stack,slack
- flag2 keywords : twitter,facebook,whatsapp
- flag3 keywords : flow,run,increase

expected  output : (message,flag1,flag2,flag3) Stack overflow contribution towards code development is increasing day by day,1,0,0

**Approach 1**

```
 val tempDF = df.withColumn("flag1",computeFlag(col("message"))).withColumn("flag2",computeFlag(col("message"))).withColumn("flag3",computeFlag(col("message")))
```

**Approach 2**

```
 val tempDF = df.withColumn("flagValues",computeMultipleFlags(col("message"))).withColumn("_tmp", split($"flagValues","#")).select($"message",$"_tmp".getItem(0).as("flag1"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("commercial"),$"_tmp".getItem(2).as("flag2"),$"_tmp".getItem(3).as("flag3")).drop("_tmp")
```

UDF : computeFlag to return 1 or 0 based on exact match of respective keywords list

UDF :  computeMultipleFlags to return # delimited result of 1 or 0 based on exact match of respective keywords of flag1, flag 2 and flag 3 : example 1#0#0

I have solved using both approaches but see/feel approach 2 to be performing better. Please advice.

- Spark data frames are parallelized by default but how does this case
  work on approach 1. Will flag1,flag2,flag3 columns be computed in
  parallel or sequential ?
- Will Spark data frame automatically parallel process my input column 
  "message" : multiple threads of multiple rows against column
  computation ?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you have used `udf` functions, which requires `column` `serialization` and `deserialization`, taking valuable time while processing.

In your first case you have called same `udf` three times using `withColumn`, which means that serialization and deserialization occured three time for each flag generation

In your second case you have defined only one `udf` function. So it is obvious to run faster and efficiently than the first one. And you have used `split` function which is a good sign.

`Dataframe`s are distributed in nature so each function call get executed parallel in each `executors` but each function will get executed sequentially i.e. **data get parallelized but functions/tasks are still sequential**.

I hope the explanation is clear

There is a better solution for your case by using [Spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) which doesn't require additional serialization and deserialization as in `udf` case. You can use the following solution.

```
df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"message", " "))
  .select($"message",
    when(array_contains($"_tmp", "stack") || array_contains($"_tmp", "slack"), "1").otherwise("0") as "flag1",
    when(array_contains($"_tmp", "twitter") || array_contains($"_tmp", "facebook") || array_contains($"_tmp", "whatsapp"), "1").otherwise("0") as "flag2",
    when(array_contains($"_tmp", "flow") || array_contains($"_tmp", "run") || array_contains($"_tmp", "increase"), "1").otherwise("0") as "flag3")
  .show(false)
```